# Loading content models and webscripts from specific directory in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

By default, Alfresco load content models and webscripts from its directories, default places where we put our code(java, javascript) and our custom content models. I would like "to tell" Alfresco to load mi stuff from a different directory. For example, Alfresco is installed in /home/Alfresco and mi stuff is in /home/mistuff. I would prefer to load all webscripts and content models inside this directory, no matter nested folders. The idea would be to add a path to default places for loading of Alfresco.

Comment: Define an absolute path like `path:///home/stuff` instead of a default import?

Comment: Can you please tell me how and where?What file should I modify?

Comment: Are you packaging your modifications/custom code in a jar file? In that case I wouldn't see the need to do this, it all depends on your building methods. However you could change tomcat to load an extra shared/classes path where your custom code/jars are located.

Comment: If we change tomcat, we do not solve the problem, for example, webscripts in javascript, tomcat would not know how to link javascript code with alfresco, do you see my point?